# Cannot query DB2 current date with EntityFramework ObjectContext.CreateQuery

Tags: .net, entity-framework, db2

I'm using DB2, Entity Framework and C# 4.0 working together fine.
My problem is when trying to get system date with the next code...

```
var query = dbcontext.CreateQuery<TResult>("SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;");
var result = query.AsEnumerable().First();
```

The query executes ok in DB2, but EF produces an exception with message "the query sintax is not valid. Near the identifier 'date' ...".

It seems that EF does its own sql parsing, but not using DB2 grammar or so.

So.. is there a way to force EF to pass the SQL "as is" to the BD?

Or maybe use a function or other variable in DB2 to not use that weird syntax (the "current date", which really appears like a column-name followed by an alias in other SQL dialects)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `CURRENT_DATE`, as well. I'm not sure if that will help any (I've not used EF with DB2)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using ObjectContext and DbContext despite the dbContext name. ObjectContext.CreateQuery takes ESQL query and not the database specific SQL query. If you want to send the database specific SQL query you need to use [ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx)